# Browser unique Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is there a unique id that represents your current browser?
I got  two applications logged in via ApiGateWay,
I want to check if they are running at the same browser or not
so I need a unique key or id for this browser

Comment: you can try uuid npm package

Comment: This package will generate a "unique" uid,  This will not work for me because I want to get this key from both applications and send it to APIGateway to check if they have the same browser ID or not.

Comment: If your server cookies the first request with a random/unique ID, then a 2nd request from that same browser will present the original cookie and you can connect the two via the unique ID in the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fingerprintjs2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingerprintjs2)

Install via npm:

```
npm install fingerprintjs2
```

Usage:

```
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
  console.log(result); //a hash, representing your device fingerprint
  console.log(components); // an array of Fingerprint components
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect some fraud actions from users, than the simplest way is to set some random string cookie.
No dependencies, no 3rd-party code, nice and simple.